# Elasticsearch - change field from not_analyzed to analyzed

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to modify property of an existing field from `not_analyzed` to `analyzed` ?

If not, what can I do in order to keep all my documents in store ?

I cannot delete mappings (because then all documents will be gone) and I need that old field as analyzed.

Comment: What version of ES are you running?

Comment: @Val ES ver. 2.2.0

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot modify an existing field, however, you can either create another field or [add a sub-field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#updating-field-mappings) to your `not_analyzed` field.

I'm going for the latter solution. So first, add a new sub-field to your existing field, like this:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/index/_mapping/type -d '{
    "properties": {
        "your_field": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "fields": {
                "sub": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Above, we've added the sub-field called `your_field.sub` (which is analyzed) to the existing `your_field` (which is `not_analyzed`)

Next, we'll need to populate that new sub-field. If you're running the latest ES 2.3, you can use the powerful [Reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html#_reindex_to_change_the_name_of_a_field)

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_reindex -d '{
  "source": {
    "index": "index"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "index"
  },
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.your_field = ctx._source.your_field"
  }
}'
```

Otherwise, you can simply use the following Logstash configuration which will re-index your data in order to populate the new sub-field

```
input {
  elasticsearch {
   hosts => "localhost:9200"
   index => "index"
   docinfo => true
  }
}
filter {
 mutate {
  remove_field => [ "@version", "@timestamp" ]
 }
}
output {
 elasticsearch {
   hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
   manage_template => false
   index => "%{[@metadata][_index]}"
   document_type => "%{[@metadata][_type]}"
   document_id => "%{[@metadata][_id]}"
 }
}
```

Comment: Sure thing, here you go.

Comment: THANK YOU Val ! :)

Comment: Always glad to help!!

Comment: Hi,
Got two questions:
1. I don't really understand why we should do the "reindex" part.
If we are adding the sub_field to the existing mapping (first part), that's not enough ?
Why should we reindex ?

2. If we are added a subfield, does my field insert will be affected ?

I mean will I continue sending:
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/index/ -d {
 "my_field" : "value"
}

or there is any change ?

Comment: 1. Because the new sub-field you created doesn't contain any data yet, that's why you need to populate it. 2. By creating a sub-field, you have nothing else to modify in your indexing process, you can do exactly the same as you used to.

Comment: 1. Oh I get it.. reindex is because old data needs to be inserted automatically also into the new sub-field, so we are re-inserting it.
2. Ok, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/mapping-multi-field-type.html

You can use this... there is something known as multi field type mapping, which allows you to have more than one mapping for a single field, and you can also query based on the field type..